# ElasticSearch Delete By Query plugin

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to download Delete-By-Query plugin of ElasticSearch but when I type "bin>plugin install delete-by-query" in command prompt, I get error in downloading.

how can i fix it?

how can i download this plugin and install it offline?

Comment: Please show the output you get.

Comment: Do you really type `bin>plugin install delete-by-query`? Use `./bin/plugin install delete-by-query` assuming you are on Linux in the elasticsearch directory.

Comment: No, I'm using windows.

Comment: It returns Failed: SocketTimeoutException[connect timed out]

Comment: I think elastic download server is down. how can i download it from another repository?

Comment: In Windows you can use backslash \ instead of `/`: `.\bin\plugin install delete-by-query`. I just tried to install the plugin and it worked without a problem.

Comment: I can't download plugin directly with link. the elastic search download server does not response to me. can you send me downloaded plugin?

Comment: According to the install output it is https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/plugin/delete-by-query/2.3.0/delete-by-query-2.3.0.zip